# pymongo.cursor.Cursor in a Django-template

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to iterate over an pymongo.cursor.Cursor object in a django-template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Pymongo cursors implement the standard Python utterable methods, so you can iterate through a cursor's values using `{% for element in cursor %}...{% endfor %}` just as you would a list or other iterable sequence.

Comment: It doesnt work. If i do {{ varialbe_name}}, I get <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x02E3AF70>. But If I do {% for element in variable_name %} {{element}} {% endfor %} I get nothing. If I iterate through it in my view before I enter the template, It works.

Comment: Normally you can only iterate a cursor once -- once you've iterated it, you've exhausted its results, and attempting to iterate it again will raise `StopIteration` immediately. To reset the cursor, use `.rewind()`, but beware that this will cause the queries to be reissued to the database as though you were iterating it for the first time.